# Conditionally specify an optional argument to a command

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I have these two new commands defined:

```tex
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        center, colback=black!20!white,
        width=.75\textwidth, boxrule=0pt, frame empty]

        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\othercommand}[1]{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        width=.75\textwidth, boxrule=0pt, frame empty]

        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
```

As you can see, both commands are almost identical, apart from the fact that the first one has `center` and `colback` arguments being passed. Is there a way I could generalize these two commands into a single command that can take an extra argument, and depending on whether that argument is present on the invocation, render either of the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `\tcbset` applies to all `tcolorbox`es in the same group level.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{sm}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\tcbset{center,colback=black!20!white}}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    width=.75\textwidth,
    boxrule=0pt,
    frame empty
  ]
  #2
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\mycommand{
  something something something something
  something something something something
  something something something something
}

\mycommand*{
  something something something something
  something something something something
  something something something something
}

\mycommand{
  something something something something
  something something something something
  something something something something
}

\end{document}
```

The *-variant applies `center` and `colback`.

[image]

Comment: +1: Is `\IfBooleanT{#1}` responsible for the `*` version? And `#2` is the actual argument of the command `\mycommand`?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The arguments are specified as `sm`. With `s` we denote a possible `*`; if there is at call time, `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{<true>}{<false>}` will return the `<true>` text, otherwise the `<false>` text. When there is no `<false>` text, we can abbreviate with `\IfBooleanT{#1}{<true>}`. With `m` a mandatory argument is specified.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of egreg's answer which takes into account that square brackets of optional arguments don't need to be matched when occurring within undelimited arguments:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{sm}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\begin{tcolorbox}[center, colback=black!20!white, }%
                    {\begin{tcolorbox}[}%
        width=.75\textwidth, boxrule=0pt, frame empty]%
    #2%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}%

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\mycommand{
  something something something something
  something something something something
  something something something something
}

\mycommand*{
  something something something something
  something something something something
  something something something something
}

\mycommand{
  something something something something
  something something something something
  something something something something
}

\end{document}
```

[image]